# EXIF: Can you calculate latitude from longitude value and true north value?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, true-north

I have an iPhone image that contains the GPS longitude and a bearing relative to True North. Is it possible to calculate the latitude from these two values?
EXIF metadata in question:

`GPS Longitude Ref:E
GPS Longitude: 153.079117 degrees E
GPS Altitude Ref: Unknown (Sea level)
GPS Altitude: 14.1651 m
GPS Date Time: 04:02:17.00
GPS Speed Ref: km/h
GPS Speed: 0
GPS Img Direction Ref: True North
GPS Img Direction: 284.7391
GPS Dest Bearing Ref: True North
GPS Dest Bearing: 284.7391
GPS Date Stamp: 2020:05:25`

I also know roughly where the photograph was taken, as in the capital city, state and country.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The Longitude value indicates only how far east or west you are. If you want to calculate Latitude (i.e. north or south), you would need a direction (bearing), **and** a distance.

It is unclear if the bearing value indicated the direction you are moving in, or the direction the camera is pointing at.

That said, it would surprise me if the EXIF data contained Longitude, but not Latitude.